# How do I update a MS Access database using excel power query?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a quick question. So I stored all the database in access (which is local) and then I use excel's power query to import the data from access. But I want whatever changes made in excel spreadsheet (That I imported information from access) to be made in access directly using power query? Is there any way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd guess perhaps a sub for onchange in VBA that submits changes to access or do it whenever the sheet is saved. Interaction between Microsoft Apps is strong through VBA so pretty sure there will be a way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good idea, but you could try something like this concept.

```
Sub ImportFromAccess()
   Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim myRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim strConn As String

   strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & "C:\your_path_here\Northwind.mdb"

   Set myRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

   FocusRow = ActiveCell.Row
   With myRecordset
       .Open "SELECT * FROM PersonInformation WHERE ID=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value, _
         strConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
         ' This assumes that ID is a number field. If it is a text field, use
         ' .Open "SELECT * FROM PersonInformation WHERE ID='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & "'", _
         strConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

      .Fields("ID").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & FocusRow).Value
      .Fields("FName").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & FocusRow).Value
      .Fields("LName").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & FocusRow).Value
      .Fields("Address").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & FocusRow).Value
      .Fields("Age").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & FocusRow).Value
      .Update
      .Close
   End With
   Set myRecordset = Nothing
   Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

AND

```
Sub UpdateRecordsInAccess()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
        "C:\your_path_here\Northwind.mdb"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open strConn

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
        lastcolumn = .Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))
    End With

        'therow = 1

        For i = 2 To lastrow
            'r = rng.Row
            'If r > 1 Then
                strSQL = "UPDATE PersonInformation SET " & _
                    "FName='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "LName='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "Address='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "Age=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value & " WHERE " & _
                    "ID=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
                conn.Execute strSQL
            'End If
            'r = r + 1
        Next i


    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am trying the way you suggested, but when i implemented the update access, it shows an error saying application defined or object error..

Comment: Tools > References > Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.8 Library

Comment: I did that, but it says application defined or object error, I posted my code that I am currently working on

Answer (score 0):

Sub UpdateRecordsInAccess()
    Dim rng As Range
    'Dim r As Long
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim strSQL As String

```
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  Source=C:\Users\username\Desktop\DatabaseResplann.mdb;"
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn


With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    lastcolumn = .Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))
End With

    'therow = 1

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        'r = rng.Row
        'If r > 1 Then
            strSQL = "UPDATE Allocation SET " & _
                "Resource Name='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value & "', " & _
                "Child PID='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value & "', " & _
                "Fct wk#='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value & "', " & _
                "Fct Hrs='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value & "', " & _
                "Fct %='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Value & "', " & _
                "Comment='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & i).Value & " WHERE " & _
                "Resource ID='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
            conn.Execute strSQL
        'End If
        'r = r + 1
    Next i


conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```

End Sub